# linux - smb/cifs Stale cp: cannot open 'file.JPG' for reading: Stale file handle

Tags: cifs, smb

I've got the following entry in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//fritz.box/fritz.nas /mnt/smb/fritz.nas cifs   user,cache=loose,nohandlecache,username=name,workgroup=WORKGROUP,password=pwd,vers=3.0         0      0
```

mounting works perfectly fine, but when I want to copy a file from the server to my local machine, I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot open 'file.JPG' for reading: Stale file handle
```

or if I use rsync:

```
rsync: [sender] send_files failed to open "path/to/file.JPG": Stale file handle (116)
        937.29K 100%  915.32MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 88 bytes  received 35 bytes  246.00 bytes/sec
total size is 937.29K  speedup is 7,803.09
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1330) [sender=v3.2.3]
```

If I set the smb version to 1 the error is gone (which I'd like to avoid due to known security issues).

I already tried changing some things with the caching (since https://forums.unraid.net/topic/86707-cifs-smb-stale-file-handle/ indicates that this is causing the issue), but is isn't working. (already tried `cache=none` in the `fstab`)

Any ideas what might be causing this (maybe it isn't the caching) or what I'm doing wrong when trying to turn off the caching?

Edit: Tested downloading a file with `smbclient` (disabled SMBv1 in advance)

[image: SMBv1 capability removed]

[image: smbclient works]

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the device supports smb v3? and have you tried to copy file with `smbclient`?

Comment: I'm sure that at least v2 is supportet, since there is an extra checkbox that has to be checked so that v1 is even allowed. And I know that without checking that checkbox it works on other computers (with e.g. windows).

Comment: ok `smbclient` is working for copying files without mounting?

Comment: Didn't tried that up to now, see the screenshots in the post for my test result (seems to be working)

Comment: good! so could you please add `noserverino` in your mount options and test again?

Comment: Nice, this works (even with v3). Could you put this into a real answer, that I can mark as the solution and if you don't mind explaining what exactly this option does (I understand it lets the client calculate the inodes numbers, but I don't quite understand how this solves the issue and why taking the inode numbers from the server is a problem in this case) this would be a nice extra ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the question we see that it can be mounted successfully and the access to files with `smbclient` is ok.
I suggested to add `noserverino` to mount options.

`noserverino` handles cases where the server can not generate a unique inode number for each file. In CIFS/SMB, files are almost always accessed (opened) by name, and it is not required that a file system be able to preserve a persistent identifier for each file (other than its name).

Some servers fill 0 for the inode number (incorrectly) making it impossible to distinguish files.

so `noserverino` simply tells the system that the destination is not an INODE server, so that the INODEs will be generated by the client.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to give you the reputation (from the bounty) that you definitely earned even now after the bounty expired?

Comment: Thanks, I think it should be still valid. there should be +100 near upvote. anyway new bounty also can be started if not currently available.